# Setup two different static folders with Nest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I would like to use Nest to serve two static applications. Basically it means I have a public folder like

```
/public
       /admin
       /main
```

In nest I do

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public/main'));
```

Now if I go to `http://localhost:3000` it will serve `/public/main/index.html`. This is good, however, when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/admin` I want `/public/admin/index.html`

One solution would be to copy everything inside `/main` directly into `public`, but that will complicate my build process, and I have the feeling that what I need is very easy, because in express you can do

```
app.use('/admin/*', app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public/admin')));
app.use(app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public/')))
```

Something like this (not tested, but it feels right :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `prefix` option to create a virtual path prefix:

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public/admin'), {prefix: '/admin'});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. Do you also have an url to documentation about this subject?

Comment: Glad it's working for you. :-) I don't think this is in the docs, I just checked the `ServeStaticOptions` interface. The code docs are pretty good.

Comment: Ok, thnx I'll do that next time!